# NSData - loading data from URL issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

Can anyone explain me why after executing this 2 lines of code for valid `NSURL`, `data = nil` and `data 2 = 52104bytes` ??

```
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aURL];

 NSData *data2 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[aURL absoluteString]];
```

Comment: How you'r dealing with `aURL`?

Comment: It might help to put your `aURL` content here :)

Comment: aURL is local path. And like I said it is valid. It is checked by the second line and other NSFileManager methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better if you use the NSURLConnection and the NSURLConnectionDelegate if aURL is a remote URL or aURL is not a local source.

Comment: Or NSURLSession if you want to be more up to date.

Comment: Honestly I was more curious why method that is supposed to work does not than looking for alternative solutions.

Comment: It depends on where is the file that you are trying to read.
If is online, you have to use the first method, if it is on locale, you have to use the second method